# Minimum possible value of n?

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $100$ countries participating in an olympiad. Suppose $n$ is a
>   positive integer such that each of the $100$ countries is willing to
>   communicate in exactly $n$ languages. If each set of $20$ countries can
>   communicate in at least one common language, and no language is common
>   to all $100$ countries, what is the minimum possible value of $n$?

I tried thinking of various cases where we can get minimum value, but I am not sure and they are very different.

My opinion- let 99 countries have a common language, so all the groups of 20 countries including the left out country will have to speak different language,so that the rule follows. So the n= (99C19) +1

Comment: Title asks maximum, text asks minimum? Maybe give the source of the problem, so we can check ...

Comment: Sorry typing errors xD

Comment: Isn't it just 2? Or that I'm interpreting the question wrongly

Comment: Well I don't know the ans. And it cannot be two I think

Comment: I think the question lacks specifics.....when it says that "each set of 20 countries...." does it mean each possible set or just a random set of 20 countries which is fixed...ie....in that case we can have only five sets but in the first case we can have (100 C 20) possible sets

Comment: Isn't the answer just 20?

Comment: Well each set of 20 countries would mean all  possible cases as if there were only 5 sets, it would have been five groups..

Comment: @RossMilikan- Why did you delete your answer...isnt it correct?

Comment: @SirJMP:  no.  I had different countries speaking different numbers of languages.

Comment: Hmm...I sensed that something was wrong but still your answer satisfied more constraints than any other answers....

Answer (score 2):

1. We have $100$ sets of languages $S_i$ of size $|S_i|\leq n$ each and for atleast one $i$ we have $|S_i|=n$.
2. We know for each draw $d$ of $20$ countries, we have at least one common language:
   $$
   \left\lvert \bigcap_{j=1}^{20} S_{d_j} \right\rvert \ge 1
   $$
3. And there is no language common to all countries:
   $$
   \bigcap_{i=1}^{100} S_i = \emptyset
   $$

This is slightly different than the question, but if we got sets with these properties we can just fill them up with random disjoint languages to get $|S_i|=n$ for all $i$, without removing any of the 2 other properties. So if we find an $n$ and sets $S_i$ with these properties this $n$ also fulfills the properties of the question.

Let $n$ be the minimal number s.t. we can find sets $S_i$ with the properties 1.,2.,3. from above, and let $S_i$ (for $i=1,...,100$) be such sets.

I claim if $m=\left\lvert \bigcup_{j=1}^{100} S_{j} \right\rvert$, the number of differet languages in total, is greater than $n+1$, we can find sets $A_i$ with the properties 1.,2.,3. and $\left\lvert \bigcup_{j=1}^{100} A_{j} \right\rvert=m-1$. Property 1. $\rightarrow\exists i$ s.t. $|S_i|=n$. W.l.o.g. $i=1$ and $\bigcup_{j=1}^{100} S_{j}=\{1,2,3,...,m\}$ and $S_1=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$. Now let for all $i=1,2,...,100$: $A_i=S_i$ if $m\notin S_i$ and $A_i=(S_i\cup\{n+1\})-\{m\}$ else. Now 1.,2.,3. is still clearly fulfilled by the sets $A_i$, so my claim follows.

So we can iterate this till $m=n+1$. Now again let $n$ be minimal again and assume $n<20$ and let $S_i$ be sets s.t. 1.,2.,3. holds and $n+1=\left\lvert \bigcup_{j=1}^{100} S_{j} \right\rvert$ (exists because of the established claim). Again w.l.o.g. $\bigcup_{j=1}^{100} S_{j}=\{1,2,3,...,n+1\}$. But now because of 3. we can find $d_1,...d_{n+1}$ s.t. $1\notin S_{d_1},2\notin S_{d_2},3\notin S_{d_3},...$ but then $$
\left\lvert \bigcap_{j=1}^{n+1} S_{d_j} \right\rvert = 0
$$
a contradiction because $n+1\leq 20$.

So $n\geq 20$.

For $n=20$ we can define the sets $S_i=\{1,2,...,21\}-\{i\}$ for $i=1,...,21$ and $S_i=S_1$ for $i=22,...,100$, which fullfills all properties. So $20\geq n$.

So $n=20$

**Idea:**
If we got a solution with $m$ languages and each country speaks less or equal to $n$ languages and atleast one speaks exaclty $n$ languages and $m>n+1$ we can construct a solution with $m-1$ languages.

Then I show that a solution with $n<20$ and $m=n+1$ can't exist.

Then I showed a construction for a solution with $n=20$ and $m=n+1$.

Comment: Can you explain in a simplified way?? It is not much clear ..

Comment: What part isn't clear? I'll then maybe can explain it in more simple terms.

Answer (score 1):

Each country can speak $20$ languages.  You need $21$ languages.  A construction to show it is possible is to number the countries from $0$ to $99$, number the languages from $0$ to $20$ and have each country speak all the languages except the one that is their country number $\bmod 21$.  Any collection of $20$ countries can only prohibit $20$ of the languages being used, so there is at least one that can be used.  To show $n \lt 20$ is not possible, take the first country as the first of the group.  Add to the group a country that does not speak each language spoken by the first country.  This will be a group of at most $20$ that cannot find a common language.

Comment: But how does ur solution assure that the countries dont have any language in common?

Comment: I do not understand "have each language spoken by the 99 countries that do not match its number.". What is matched against what here?

Comment: How is this possible if country $1$ has to accept $n=21$ languages, and only $20$ are available to it?

Comment: @mvw:  I misread the question as asking for the smallest set of languages.  Yes, the proper $n$ is $20$, and my first construction shows that $20$ can work.  I need to work on the proof that it is minimal.

Comment: Can you please explain why n is 20?

Comment: That is exactly what I did.  Each country speaks $20$ languages, which is how you defined $n$.  I showed a construction with $n=20$ that works, then showed that no smaller $n$ would work.

Answer (score 0):

It just asks minimum, why is there a need for combination?

Just rewrite the text as inequality with respect to n.

$\text{20 countries} = \text{1 language}\\
\text{1 country} = \dfrac{1}{20} \text{language} \\ 
\text{100 country} = \dfrac{100}{20} = \text{5 language} \\ 
\implies n \ge 5 \\ 
\implies \mathrm{min}(n) = 5
$

Comment: May you show a construction where $n=5$ is compatible with the condition?

Comment: But each country is part of many groups! So not only 5 groups are possible

Comment: I think this solution is incorrect...the question is not as simple as it seems to be...

Comment: Yes I too think so

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying every set of twenty countries needs to have a different common language?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to model this task:

1. We have $100$ sets of languages $S_i$ of size $n$ each.
2. We know for each draw $d$ of $20$ countries, we have at least one common language:
   $$
   \left\lvert \bigcap_{j=1}^{20} S_{d_j} \right\rvert \ge 1
   $$
3. And there is no language common to all countries:
   $$
   \bigcap_{i=1}^{100} S_i = \emptyset
   $$
   which implies $n > 1$.

No idea yet, what discrete maths problem might fit here.

Comment: I thought about it the same way. I came to the solution $n=20$, but I'm still looking for possible mistakes.